# Cuts up Python strings

Tags: python, strings

Please tell me what you think of this its my first try and I have only been learning Python for 3 days now, works with both 'index' and 'find':

```
data = ["XBOX 360 | 150 | New",
        "PlayStation 3 | 35 | Broken",
        "Windows 8 | 275 | New"]

Id = 0
one = data[Id].index("|")
two = data[Id].index("|", one+1)

product = data[Id][:one]
price = data[Id][one+2:two]
condition = data[Id][two+2:]

print(product)
print(price)
print(condition)

#Just add more like these:
#three = data[Id].index("|", two+1)
#four = data[Id].index("|", three+1)
#etc... If you want to add more 'Pipes'
#Add one to each 'pipe' no more then that or you'll get an error

#You can add as many new 'data' items as you want
#just change the 'Id' to view them
```

Answer (score 3):

First, there is no need to use `index()` method for finding the position of next and next delimiter (and then use it for slicing) - Python is able to split the string at a higher level - pinpoint the delimiter and then use the `split()` method:

```
   DELIMITER = " | "                        # we will use it for splitting the string

   "XBOX 360 | 150 | New".split(DELIMITER)  # the result will be ["XBOX 360", "150", "New"]
```

As you may see from the comment, the result is a list of individual parts.

---

Second - so we now have the list of the appropriate parts of the string.
Let give it the name `parts` - so `parts` will be the list:

```
   ["XBOX 360", "150", "New"]
```

(You may obtain it by the command `parts = data[0].split(DELIMITER)` in your code.)

Now instead of using indices for getting individual parts, i. e. `"XBOX 360"`, `"150"`, and `"New"`:

```
   product   = parts[0]
   price     = parts[1]
   condition = parts[2]
```

you may just unpack the `parts` list:

```
   product, price, condition = parts
```

---

Third, fourh, fifth, ... - I'm not going to overload you :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are doing things the hard way, there is a python function to cut up strings namely the `.split()` method

Thus to make it easier to use and more general I can rewrite your code like this:

```
data = ["XBOX 360 | 150 | New",
        "PlayStation 3 | 35 | Broken",
        "Windows 8 | 275 | New"]

# Here I loop through the data
# Thus I read each row starting with the XBOX360 line and ending at Windows 8
for row in data:
    # Use .split() to split the string with a specific char(set)
    product_info = row.split(' | ')

    # Tuple unpacking
    product, price, condition = product_info

    # Use pretty formatting
    print ('\nProduct: {}'.format(product))
    print ('Price: {}'.format(price))
    print ('Condition: {}'.format(condition ))
```

Try it out for yourself to see the difference, and if unclear what is going on you can always ask me

Comment: `[ [ print(word.strip)  for word in row.split()]  for row in data]`